# How to create an operator-> for a class unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have to implement a simple "unique_ptr" class supporting only a constructor, destructor, –>, *, and release(). And I did below.

However, it feels weird to write "up.operator->()" to get the pointer p. I would be more logical to write "up->p". But how do I do that? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T>
class unique_ptr
{
    T *p;

public:        
    unique_ptr(T *ptr)
        : p{ptr}
    {
    }
    ~unique_ptr() { delete p; }


    T *operator->() const { return p; } // returns a pointer
    T operator*() const { return *p; }
    T *release()
    {
        T *ptr = p;
        p = nullptr;
        return ptr;
    }
};

template <class T>
void print(const unique_ptr<T> &up, const std::string &s)
{
    std::cout << s << " up.operator->(): " << up.operator->() << '\n';
    std::cout << s << " up.operator*(): " << up.operator*() << '\n'; 
}

int main()
try
{
    int *ptr = new int(10);

    unique_ptr<int> up(ptr);
    print(up, "up: ");

}

catch (std::exception &e)
{
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "exception\n";
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: I would be more concerned with your `T operator*()` which creates a copy of `T` and won't allow you to modify the pointed object (ex. `*up = 5;` won't work). It should return a reference (`T& operator*()`).

Comment: It is important to apply [The Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) when writing a smart pointer. Anyone could make a copy of you `unique_ptr` as it is now.

Comment: If you want to have access to the underlying pointer, do as the ancients did and write a member function that returns it. E.g., see [`std::unique_ptr::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get).

Comment: Side note: reusing names from the standard library is just asking for trouble, especially if you use `using namespace std` anywhere. You may want to consider picking a better name.

Comment: @Brian, yep, I wrote that function (but didn't posted). But I thought something could be done with improving "->". (it's an exercise from Programming Principles and Practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it feels weird to write "up.operator->()" to get the pointer p.

It feels weird because the member access operator is not generally used to get a pointer to the object (although you can do it using the `operator->()` syntax, as you demonstrated). Member access operator is used to access members of the object. In your example, you have a unique pointer of `int`. `int` doesn't have a member, so it doesn't make sense to use the member access operator.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
struct S {
    int member;
};

unique_ptr<S> up(new S{10});
int value_of_member = up->member;
```

> would be more logical to write "up->p"

That wouldn't be logical unless `p` is a member of the pointed object.

> How to create an operator-> for a class unique_ptr

Like you did in the example. As far as I can tell, there was no problem with how you create the operator, but rather how to use it.

---

P.S. Your unique pointer is copyable, movable and assignable, but those operations are horribly broken leading to undefined behaviour. See rule of 5.

Comment: thanks eerorika... now I understand the confusion! I'll also read the rules.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in comments this implementation of a single ownership smart pointer is incomplete and the `operator*()` is incorrect in that it doesn't return a reference and thus does not facilitate making assignments through the pointer.

However to answer the question,

> it feels weird to write "up.operator->()" to get the pointer p. I
> would be more logical to write "up->p". But how do I do that?

Well you wouldnt want to do that as `p` is part of the private implementation of your smart pointer class. It is weird to write `up.operator->()` because that is not how the `->` is typically used. It is typically used as shorthand to access the members of a struct or class that is slightly less verbose than the `*` operator in combination with member access via `.`. To use your pointer then in a less weird way you need the template parameter to be instantiated with some type that has fields, e.g.

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
};

void print(const unique_ptr<foo>& up, const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << s << " up.operator->(): " << up->bar << '\n';
    std::cout << s << " up.operator*(): " << (*up).bar << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<foo> up(new foo{ 42 });
    print(up, "up: ");

}
```

Comment: thanks jwezorek, now it's clear what I was doing wrong!